# Can you form the "spectrum" of a sheaf of algebras?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If X is a scheme, we know there is a one-one correspondence between quasi-coherent
sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-algebras on X and affine morphisms $Y \longrightarrow X$

But what about arbitrary (not necessarily quasi-coherent) sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-algebras? Do they correspond to schemes $Y\longrightarrow X$?

It seems to me that given a morphism $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ of schemes,
for any $U\subseteq X$, the association $U\mapsto \mathcal O_Y(f^{-1}(U))$
defines a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-algebras. That's one direction. Does it not work in the other direction for some reason?

Comment: IIRC Hartshorne discusses the $\mathbf{Spec}$ (notice the boldness) of such a sheaf of algebras (in some exercise?); surely, he discusses the $\mathbf{Proj}$ of a sheaf of graded algebras.

Comment: At least all I could find in Hartshorne is Spec of sheaves of quasi-coherent algebras. I tried several obvious sources: Hartshorne, Vakil's notes and some google searches, but both Proj and Spec appear to be for quasi-coherent sheaves of algebras.

Comment: Ah. It may be the case that I did not recalled correctly :-) But is quasi-coherence really used for what you want?

Comment: Quasi-coherence definitely matters in the proof. I had forgotten about the quasi-coherence, tried to prove it generally, got stuck...then pulled out Hartshorne and said: Ah! They assumed quasi-coherent! :P But I really want to know if the general result is true.

Comment: For any $f$ quasicompact, I'm pretty sure your construction will produce a quasicoherent sheaf. So most morphisms still have to do with quasicoherent sheaves, and your inverse construction would have to produce non-quasicompact morphisms. I'm not sure if you can get every non-quasicoherent sheaf by gluing infinitely many affine schemes together. However, if there is one way to do that, there will always be lots and lots of ways, and it seems unlikely that you can pick the best, canonical one. Do you want your construction to give a unique scheme? Or do you just want it to give a scheme?

Comment: " I'm not sure if you can get every non-quasicoherent sheaf by gluing infinitely many affine schemes together. ".  I agree. If say X is over complex numbers and I take the sheaf A defined by A(U)=ring of continuous complex valued functions from $U^{an}$. I find it hard to imagine what the associated scheme for this sheaf of algebras would look like.

Comment: So, I guess the result isn't true in general. I was worried I was missing something obvious. Thanks folks!!!

Comment: Take $X$ to be a single point.  What is it you want to say in that case?

Answer (score 9):

You could ask about this in the category of locally ringed spaces, rather than just schemes.  For every locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, and for every sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras, there is a locally ringed space, $(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$, a morphism of locally ringed spaces, $$(\pi,\pi^\#):(S,\mathcal{O}_S)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X),$$ and a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras, $\phi:\pi^*\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{O}_S$, that represents the contravariant functor from the category of locally ringed spaces over $X$ to the category of sets that associates to each morphism of locally ringed spaces, $(f,f^\#):(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, the set of morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-algebras, $\psi:f^*\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{O}_X$.  Of course when $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme and $\mathcal{A}$ is quasi-coherent, $(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ is isomorphic (over $X$) to $\textbf{Spec}_X(\mathcal{A})$ as constructed in Hartshorne's book.  In this sense, the locally ringed space $(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ deserves to be called "Spec".

Comment: In their paper « Factorisation de Stein topologique. Découpe », Malgoire and Voisin use this construction in a topological setting. So let $X$ be a topological space, $F$ a closed subset, $j\colon U\to X$ the immersion of the complementary open subset, and set $\mathcal A=j_*(\mathbf Z/2)_U$. The spectrum of this algebra is a topological space $Y$ equipped with a  morphism to $X$, whose fibers are compact and totally disconnected.  This space $Y$ is the space obtained by cutting $X$ with scissors along the closed subset $F$.